# Implementing overload methods for subtypes of an abstract class in C#

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm new to C#, and I would really like to implement specific different methods for each subtype of a defined abstract class, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the compiler to do this properly. For example:

```
public abstract class MasterClass { }
public class SubClass1 : MasterClass { }
public class SubClass2 : MasterClass { }

public class SeparateClass
{
    public void HandleMasterClass(MasterClass item)
    {
       /*
       stuff generic to both subclasses...
       */
       SpecificMethod(item)
    }

    public void SpecificMethod(SubClass1 item)
    {
        //something specific to SubClass1
    }

    public void SpecificMethod(SubClass2 item)
    {
        //something specific to SubClass2
    }
}
```

This returns an error in compiling because there is no `SpecificMethod(MasterClass item)`, but what I really want is for it to choose the right method based on the subclass without having to write separate `HandleMasterClass(SubClass1 item)` and `HandleMasterClass(SubClass2 item)` methods because they are mostly the same code

my main language is Jula so I'm very used to relying on multiple dispatch and doing this kind of thing. I know its probably not idiomatic in C#, so how would I do this better?

EDIT: showing that the methods are not free but part of a separate class

here's a better concrete example

```
public abstract class MasterClass { public abstract int Stuff(); }
public class SubClass1 : MasterClass
{
    public override int Stuff() { /*calculate and return an int*/ }
}

public class SubClass2 : MasterClass
{
    public override int Stuff() { /*calculate and return an int*/ }
}

public class MasterClassDictionary
{
    public Dictionary<int, SubClass1> subClass1Dict{get;} = new Dictionary<int, SubClass1>()
    public Dictionary<int, SubClass2> subClass2Dict{get;} = new Dictionary<int, SubClass2>()

    public void Add(MasterClass item)
    {
        int val = item.Stuff();
        AddToDict(val, item);
    }

    void AddToDict(int val, SubClass1 item) { subClass1Dict[val] = item; }
    void AddToDict(int val, SubClass2 item) { subClass2Dict[val] = item; }

}
```

I know this is a bit of a contrived example, but its similar to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you may make one method accepting a "master class" and use an as-is check or whatever. Also you can do the same in handlemasterclass aswell

Comment: I didn't mention, but the methods are in a separate class doing stuff for that

Comment: edited to show that

Comment: I personally like to do that because I dont usually look at the edit history when reading other people's posts, and the edit note puts comments like yours above in context. Think of it as a code comment explaining why something was edited, not just the edit

Comment: One solution is to cast item as dynamic (  SpecificMethod( (dynamic) item)). I prefer strongly typed solutions though.

Comment: Here is an easy tutorial on how to implement an absract class https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/abstract-classes/ You can ovverride abstract methods in your case ovverride and implement `SpecificMethod` for each class

Comment: I think you have the order of operations inverted. In your code, you start with the base class then try to call a method of an implemented type. The compiler doesn't know what implemented type when you make that call. You need to start with the child class, and from there call a common base method.

Comment: I guess I'm hoping for a solution that forces the compiler to make separate HandleMasterClass methods for each subtype. Maybe its not possible?

Comment: Then declare `HandleMasterClass` in the abstract class and override it in each implementation.

Comment: The standard design pattern here is the "visitor pattern", but its a somewhat complicated pattern.

Comment: FYI if you mark your receiver as "dynamic", you will effectively get multiple dispatch, but it is **not cheap**. It starts the compiler again at runtime to resolve the dispatch. The result is cached, so if it is in a loop it's not too terrible, but still, probably it would be better to find a statically typed solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard design pattern for this situation is the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This is a somewhat complicated pattern, but the basic idea is that the subclasses know what type they are so we are going to call over to them via an virtual method called "Accept" and they will pass themselves back as a reference. The method they call back is called Visit and is overloaded for all the possible subclasses. Here is an implementation for your example:

```
public abstract class MasterClass
{
    public abstract int Stuff();

    // New method that all subclasses will have to implement.
    // You could also have this be virtual with an implementation
    // for Visit(MasterClass) to provider a default behavior.
    public abstract void Accept(IVisitor visitor);
}

public class SubClass1 : MasterClass
{
    public override int Stuff() => 0;

    // We must override this even though its the "same" code in both subclasses
    // because 'this' is a reference to a different type.
    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public class SubClass2 : MasterClass
{
    public override int Stuff() => 1;

    // We must override this even though its the "same" code in both subclasses
    // because 'this' is a reference to a different type.
    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}

public interface IVisitor
{
    // Need an overload for all subclasses.
    void Visit(SubClass1 item);
    void Visit(SubClass2 item);
}

public class MasterClassDictionary
{
    public Dictionary<SubClass1, int> subClass1Dict { get; } = new Dictionary<SubClass1, int>();
    public Dictionary<SubClass2, int> subClass2Dict { get; } = new Dictionary<SubClass2, int>();

    public void Add(MasterClass item)
    {
        int val = item.Stuff();
        var visitor = new Visitor(this, val);
        item.Accept(visitor);
    }

    void AddToDict(SubClass1 item, int val) { subClass1Dict[item] = val; }

    void AddToDict(SubClass2 item, int val) { subClass2Dict[item] = val; }

    // Provides the visitor implementation that holds any state that might
    // be needed and dispatches to the appropriate method.
    private class Visitor : IVisitor
    {
        private MasterClassDictionary _parent;
        private int _value;

        public Visitor(MasterClassDictionary parent, int val)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            _value = val;
        }

        public void Visit(SubClass1 item) => _parent.AddToDict(item, _value);

        public void Visit(SubClass2 item) => _parent.AddToDict(item, _value);
    }
}
```

That said, C# has added pattern matching with switch that would look substantially simpler. It's only downside is that it is doing more type checks which might be slower if this is in some really performance sensitive code, but is certainly going to be faster than using `dynamic`:

```
public void Add(MasterClass item)
{
    int val = item.Stuff();
    switch (item)
    {
        case SubClass1 i: AddToDict(i, val); break;
        case SubClass2 i: AddToDict(i, val); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I'm trying to write very performance sensitive code (which is the reason for using C# in the first place rather than Julia or Python) so I'm trying to leave as much as possible to the compiler while still saving myself as much typing effort as I can. I like the generic IVisitor interface

Comment: @stords If this is *really* perf sensitive code, I'd probably want to benchmark both ways. The visitor pattern show makes an allocation that the switch does not. Depending on the scenario the memory pressure might be a bigger concern, but this could be alleviated by pooling and re-using the visitor objects.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you want to put code specific to a class inside that class. So your abstract class would define the specific method signature, using the [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) keyword, and the implementation would live inside the class, using the [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) keyword, like this:

```
public abstract class MasterClass {
    public abstract void SpecificMethod();
}

public class SubClass1 : MasterClass {
    public override void SpecificMethod()
    {
        //something specific to SubClass1
        // use the this keyword to access the instance

    }
}

public class SubClass2 : MasterClass {
    public override void SpecificMethod()
    {
        //something specific to SubClass2
        // use the this keyword to access the instance
    }
}

public class SeparateClass
{
    public void HandleMasterClass(MasterClass item)
    {
      /*
      stuff generic to both subclasses...
      */
      item.SpecificMethod()
    }
}
```

Per your comment, this is how I might implement the thing in your concrete example, though it may not meet your requirements:

```
public class MasterClassDictionary
{
    public Dictionary<int, SubClass1> subClass1Dict{get;} = new Dictionary<int, SubClass1>()
    public Dictionary<int, SubClass2> subClass2Dict{get;} = new Dictionary<int, SubClass2>()

    public void Add(MasterClass item)
    {
        int val = item.Stuff();

        if (item is SubClass1)
        {
            subClass1Dict[val] = item;
        }

        if (item is SubClass2)
        {
            subClass2Dict[val] = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way to say it is that abstract base classes shouldn't be aware of or reference their subclasses.

Comment: Couldn't save my edit (not long enough) ... `overrides` keyword should be `override`

Comment: I added a more concrete example to show why I'm not just doing that. Can you tell me if you would still take this approach?

Comment: Thanks, @GreggL, totally missed that one.

Comment: @stords, I think in your concrete example I'd probably just do some type checking in the `Add` method of the `MasterClassDictionary` using the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) keyword to make sure that the items ended up in the right dictionary. It's tough to make further recommendations without knowing more about your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably go with that. The real scenario is that they are not Dictionaries but a custom implementation of a Heap, and I need to be able to pop the highest priority one of a given type on demand.